# Benefit in using Image Source: `Azure Container Registry` over Image Source: `Private Registry` in Azure wizard `Create Web App`?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps, azure-container-registry, azure-web-app-for-containers

Is there any benefit in using option Image Source: `Azure Container Registry` over Image Source: `Private Registry` in Azure wizard `Create Web App` ?

---

We are having one common Azure subscription in which we created Azure Container Registry. The registry contains several Repositories containing Docker images that we use as source for our containers.

But we were also considering testing the Docker images in an Azure App Service that we wanted to create in different Azure subscription dedicated to testing.

In the wizard "Create Web App", we encountered following two behaviors:

- we selected Options: `Single container`, Image Source: `Azure Container Registry`
  and we see error near Registry field: `There are no ACR Registries in the selected subscription`
  and here we have left the wizard.
- we selected Options: `Single container`, Image Source: `Private Registry` and we filled-in the url, username and password to access the Azure Container Registry along with other settings and the Azure Web App was created, started running and provided the content based on the target Docker image.

So the question is: Is there any benefit in using option Image Source: `Azure Container Registry` over Image Source: `Private Registry` in Azure wizard `Create Web App` ?

If the answer to question is yes, what are the options to use it in different Azure subscriptions? Should we create Azure Container Registry in every subscription and replicate the Docker images several times?

Answer (score 1):

**Azure container registry** is the default ACR which should have provided a seamless integration without users, password, url...
Because you created the Web App in another subscription then it didn't show up.

**Private registry** is any registry on the internet, or you yourself host it somewhere so at the end it has the ability to connect to ACR but with providing details.

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/Azure/acr/issues/345) for your scenario and seems it's not resolved yet.